# What to do about "what's new in <version #>" questions

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions, android-versions

Case in point: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/whats-new-in-2-3-6-on-the-nexus-one

There are others, however.

(This particular question is *way* too specific, asking about a bug release version on a particular device, but it should illustrate the point.)

Anyway, what do we want to do with questions like this? There is no official "changelog" we can refer people to, except where there is a **major** revision. Even so, a change to just the third node in the version number is almost certainly nothing but bug fixes.

Frankly, I think questions like this should be closed as "too localized", but I'm afraid we're going to keep getting them.

Would it be worth it to have canonical questions for each of the major versions? We could add point-releases like this to the major version if we can suss out what was changed.

Comment: [This](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/whats-new-in-android-2-3-gingerbread) might be a good place to start, but I think it's too wordy for what I'm envisioning.

Comment: @AlEverett That seems like a good starting point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Frankly, I think questions like this should be closed as "too localized", but I'm afraid we're going to keep getting them.

They're *way* too localized. Even a question like "what's new in Android 4.0?" would be marginal (I'd point them to Wikipedia, I look up what's new in each Google Chrome release on Wikipedia for example).

An 2.3.x release on *a specific phone model* (I'm assuming vendors tweak each release?) is *incredibly* localized and trivial.

Comment: So do we need a canonical, "here's where to find version release notes" sort of question we can point these people to?

Comment: @Jeff: I'm more than content to close these. I don't know that most of the community agrees with me, though.

Comment: @GAThrawn that's a great idea

Comment: @GAThrawn: Make it so!